# React cloneElement, how to modify 'this'?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a JSX file with:

1 a custom component 'Parent'

2 some predefined UI components from semantic-ui: 'Segment'

```
<Parent lst={["a","b","c"]}>
  <Segment>
    <Segment>
      {this.props.content}
    </Segment>
  </Segment>
</Parent>
```

The idea is that the Parent component will iterate over this.props.lst and use React.cloneElement to clone the outer Segment component with  the 'content' property set to each list item.

Unfortunately this doesn't work because:
1. A Segment will not pass it's properties to children
2. 'this' in '{this.props.content}' in the inner Segment component points to the Parent's props.

I tried using refs:

```
<Parent lst={["a","b","c"]}>
  <Segment ref="outer">
    <Segment>
      {this.refs.outer.props.content}
    </Segment>
  </Segment>
</Parent>
```

After using React.cloneElement on 'outer' this errors, this.refs.outer is undefined in the inner Segment

How to clone a hierarchy of components and set properties on one of the inner components?

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/78061

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly on what your intent is (in terms of props visibility/accessibility), you can pass `this.props.content` as a prop to the `<Parent />` component, apart from `lst`. That way, `Parent` can perform the cloning of its children an set the `content` property to the outer `Segment` since it has access from within.

```
<Parent lst={["a","b","c"]} content={this.props.content}>
  <Segment>
    <Segment>
      {this.props.content}
    </Segment>
  </Segment>
</Parent>
```

An then inside `Parent` render's method:

```
render() {
  return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props.content);
}
```

That should keep the original children of the outer `Segment` component, since [cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) will only replace existing children if new children are passed as the 3rd argument of the method.

Comment: Probably my question was not very clear. I have tried to wrap the problem in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/78061/ Can you have a look at it?